# Locally Invoke AWS Lambda functions using container

Tags: go, aws-lambda, containers, query-string

So i have been trying to explore the Lambda container image

i have a lambda function as follows

**test.go:**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)


func handleRequest(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {

    fmt.Println("Request %s \n\n", request)
    fmt.Println("Context %s \n\n", ctx)

    name := request.QueryStringParameters["name"]

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{Body: fmt.Sprint("Hello %s", name), StatusCode: 200}, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handleRequest)
}
```

My Docker File as :

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-go

COPY bin/test /var/task

CMD [ "test" ]
```

I build the above docker file with tag as testing_go, and run it as follows

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 testing_go
```

and try to invoke this as follows

```
curl -X GET --url http://localhost:8080/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations?name=JOHN --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{}'
```

i see that the container log shows the following for the values of context and request

```
Request %s 

 {   map[] map[] map[] map[] map[] map[] {        {            }  map[]   0 }  false}
Context %s 

 context.Background.WithDeadline(2020-12-23 03:07:06.186819041 +0000 UTC [325h22m17.998420615s]).WithValue(type *lambdacontext.key, val <not Stringer>).WithValue(type string, val )
map[]
```

Question:

1. how do i invoke the function locally via curl so that i can capture the Querystring parameters in my Go lang code?

It would be really helpful if someone can help me out with this .

EDIT:
After breaking my head for a while i was able to figure it out .
answer to it was

```
curl -X GET --url http://localhost:8080/2015-1/functions/function/invocations --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"queryStringParameters": {"name": "john"}}'
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: @mh-cbon how do i invoke the function via curl so that i can capture the querystring parameters

Comment: I fail to grasp that "capture the querystring parameters" part. What does "to capture" mean here? To be fetched by `curl` and printed by it to the terminal? If yes, what `curl` dumps if you pass it the `-i` command-line option? Does it display the name? What if you enclose the wole URL passed to `curl` in quotes so that the `?` character is not interpreted by a shell by a chance?

Comment: You also consistently misuse functions of the `fmt` package; please read up its documentation on what's the difference between `fmt.Foo` and `fmt.Foof` family of functions.

Comment: @kostix what i mean is , when i make a curl request , My Go lang code doesn't seem to have any values for request.QueryStringParameters["name"].

Comment: make it an answer rather than edit your post. I suspected that when i read associated issue to https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/issues/42 but could not believe it would be correct (note that this is the issue #42 ^^ ) besides, worth to read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-handler.html

Answer (score 5):

After trying out a bunch of stuff , i figured out that if we want to invoke my lambda locally and pass a value as query string parameter I need to do it as follows.

```
curl -X GET --url http://localhost:8080/2015-1/functions/function/invocations --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"queryStringParameters": {"name": "john"}}'
```